# Manipulating JSON data on the client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatable

Need some suggestion on manipulating JSON data on the client side.

Any tips on how to convert TYPE1 into TYPE2 in JS/jQuery?

**Convert this (TYPE1):**

```
{
    "0": {
        "Field1": "Val1",
        "Field2": "Val2",
        "Field3": "Val3"
    }, 
    "1": {
        "Field1": "Val1",
        "Field2": "Val2",
        "Field3": "Val3"
    }
}
```

**Into this (TYPE2):**

```
{
    "SomeName": [
        [
            "Val1",
            "Val3",
            "Val3"],
        [
            "Val4",
            "Val5",
            "Val6"]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Where is `SomeName` coming from?

Comment: What is `[..]` in your example TYPE2? It's not clear if both sets of `"Val1", "Val2", "Val3"` from TYPE1 have been combined.

Comment: @MCL - this is only the name - it does not exist in TYPE1

Comment: @nnnnnn - `[..]` would be next object in the JSON -  `"1"`

Comment: Alright. Now, that we've established that: What have you tried?

Comment: @MCL - `http://jsfiddle.net/XbUVh/`

Comment: You're using jQuery without even importing the library? Did you even attempt to run your fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var oldObj = {
    "0": {
        "Field1": "Val1",
        "Field2": "Val2",
        "Field3": "Val3"
    }, 
    "1": {
        "Field1": "Val1",
        "Field2": "Val2",
        "Field3": "Val3"
    }
}

var newObj = {"SomeName":[]};           // Initialize a new Object

for(var key in oldObj){                 // Loop through the old item,
    var item = [];                      // Create a temporary variable for each sub-item.
    for(var subKey in oldObj[key]){     // Loop through the sub-item
        item.push(oldObj[key][subKey]); // Push the sub-item's data to the temp var.
    }
    newObj.SomeName.push(item);         // Push the temp var to the new Object.
}
```